can't debug react native app , Debugging connection was closed. Reason: WebSocket disconnected - Expo Sdk 50
I'm running into problems with debugging react native app using expo, on both emulator and physical android device , I'm getting the same error .
after I run the development build :
*when press 'j' I get the following error:

debugging connection was closed reason : websocket disconnected .
reconnect when ready by reopening dev tools .

where have I done wrong ?
steps to reproduce :

npx expo start --dev-client

I ran npx expo install --check

Dependencies are up to date

environment
OS: Windows 10
Expo ; Managed Workflow ,
expo: "~50.0.14",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
expo/cli :"0.17.8"
